# What should I do with these old domain names?

Tags: domains, parking

I purchased some domain names a few years ago intending to build something on them. I haven't had the time to develop any of the websites, but I still think they have potential.

What would you do? *Let them expire, sell them, create a sign-up page to gauge user interest, something else?*

Are there any resources/methods/tools you can recommend to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I haven't found a good way of dealing with those. What I'll probably do is redirect them to a single page mentioning that I'm willing to sell the domain name for a fair price (if I can get the domain appraised, I'd show the price).

Comment: List the domains, perhaps I'll buy them! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this site to get an understanding of the value of domain names in general, http://www.igoldrush.com/domain-guide/domain-buying-and-selling/determining-the-value-of-your-domain-names/.

There are some sites that will give you quotes. GoDaddy gives free quotes but they really only look at how many visits your site has had over a period of time.

In general, domain names aren't worth much unless they have short, easy-to-recognize and remember names, and are a .com.

If your domain names aren't obviously worth any money then I would suggest letting them expire or you could just hold on to them for the annual registration fee which runs around $10 until you find a better use for them.

Answer (score 2):

Sell them at [Flippa.com](http://flippa.com).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how high quality these domain names are. If you think you could get a decent price for them at auction, I would go that route. Otherwise, I would let them expire and make their way into the market.

Comment: s/there/their/.

Comment: @ChrisF one of the better comments I have come across.  Cheers.  :-)